# Intel Core i5-3210M vs Intel Core i7-3610QM for programming task?

Tags: laptop, cpu

The title states the two processors I am concerned with, but the core of my question is this.

Does one really need a high end processor for programming in Java & Web Development / Running MySQL / Oracle?  Everything else I intend to use my computer for is relatively light, and could be handled by a system with a much slower processor.  Am I going to find my programming work significantly slowed down if I decide to save money?  Should I instead decide to purchase a system with the faster processor, because it will make a **significant** difference in my programming productivity?

I realize shopping questions are off topic, and I am not asking for a recommendation on which product to purchase.  I am instead (again) asking if a high end processor is really necessary for the programming I intend to do?

Comment: Welcome to Superuser. Please read the [FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq) to know how to make questions and what kind of questions you could ask here. Unfortunatly, shopping recomendations are off-topic.

Comment: I am sorry about it.

Comment: Sorry Optimus... I tried to re-word your question... I should have realized that **my** editing it would guarantee it's closure though.  I hope the answers you got were good enough for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely not an issue. Most "development" is sitting at a text editor, is it not? Even your databases are going to be sitting idle 90% of the time.  I have a Core i5 for my home dev box, and it is blazing fast.

It's the RAM (for running lots of programs simultaneously) and Hard Drive speed (opening those programs, saving lots of data) that tend to matter, in my opinion.

My [home dev box](http://jonathonreinhart.blogspot.com/2011/10/new-pc.html) is a Core i5 with 8GB RAM, but with a Crucial SSD, and suits me just fine (and I run multiple VMs, IDEs, browser windows, etc).

Answer (score 0):

I'm developing a Unity game with an I3 laptop , most programming doesn't require a top notch pc . Now animation( like using Maya and 3D Max) is a different story .

You should be fine with ether one( I prefer to buy the cheapest PC that gets the job done- since they get faster every year anyway ) .